# Using If statement in a pandas data set

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have been trying to use an if statement for a pandas dataset, but I keep getting this error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My code:

```
if (df['Year'] == 2013):
print(df['Name'])
```

Comment: You are trying to compare a single value to a vector of values, that won't work. Do you intend to iterate through the dataframe to print the name when the year is 2013 ?

Comment: @MohamedAliJAMAOUI.. Yes, That is what I am trying to do

Comment: This should work for you `for _,v in df.iterrows(): 
  if v["year"] == "2013": 
    print(v["name"])`